# detach folders from htm files

Tags: python, html, docx

I converted many docx files to htm in order to examine with python script. System is offline and cannot update in order to use docx library. After converting the files to htm there is a folder with the same name as the htm file. If I delete the folder it deletes the htm file that sits outside the folder. How can detach the two so I can delete the folder. Thank you.

Comment: How are you deleting the folder? My guess is that the folder contains files that are resources needed by the HTML file, eg CSS files and image files. If you delete that folder the HTML file will not render properly in a browser.

Comment: I just need to read the file and extract particular lines from the file pro grammatically with python. I just need raw text from the file. To try to delete I was simply clicking on the folder and hitting the delete button.

Comment: It doesn't  make much sense to me ... On which OS are you running ?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to detaching the folders was to copy the contents of each file to a .txt file with the same name. Then, I can parse the data in it. This works out fine and I don't need to worry about the folders since I'm saving the new files in a different directory.